# Inverse of $f(x) = \frac{x}{\log(x)}$

Tags: logarithms, inverse-function

$\pi(x)$ is defined as number of primes less than or equal to x. Gauss showed that $\pi(x) \approx \frac{x}{log(x)}$. I want to calculate the inverse of that approximation because I want to estimate how far should I sieve in order to get the number of primes that I want. Here are the steps that I took.

$$\begin{align}y &= \frac{x}{\log(x)}\\ x &= y \log(x) \\ e^x&=e^{y\log(x)} \\ e^x &= (e^{\log(x)})^y \\ e^x &= x^y\end{align}$$

I am stuck at this point. How can I calculate $y$ in terms of $x$?

Comment: For an exact formula, use the [Lambert W function](https://tinyurl.com/ycovwdfc), but in your case a numerical method like Newton's method will do.

Comment: I believe you can't do it analytically.

Answer (score 4):

Resorting to Lambert's $W$ is a little overkill.

With $$x=y\ln y,$$ we have

$$\frac x{\log x}=\frac{y\ln y}{\ln(y\ln y)}=\frac{y\ln y}{\ln y+\ln\ln y}\approx y.$$

Given that the distribution is anyway approximate, this can be a sufficient approximation of the inverse. Or you can use it as a starting value for Newton's iterations (use few of them anyway).

Comment: $x = y / \ln y$ I think? division not multiplication?

Comment: @Claude: the problem statement says $y=x/\log x$, then $x\approx y\log y$.

Comment: oh, I see now what you are doing

Comment: Using Newton, the next iteration gives you a better approximation: $x \approx y \ln(y) + y \ln(\ln(y))$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael In the setting of the question, is the second-order term meaningful? (I.e., is is consistent with the original approximation of the prime counting function?)

Comment: I don't follow. How did you arrive to $x = y lny$? I think it is supposed to be $x=y ln x$

Comment: @yasar Try to plug it: set $x := y\ln y$. Then $$\frac{x}{\ln x} = \frac{y\ln y}{\ln(y\ln y))} = \frac{y\ln y}{\ln y + \ln\ln y} = \frac{y}{1+\frac{\ln\ln y}{\ln y}} = y - y\frac{\ln\ln y}{\ln y} +   o\left(y\frac{\ln\ln y}{\ln y} \right) = y + o(y)$$

Comment: So, since $y\frac{\ln\ln y}{\ln y}$ is close to zero, we can say that $x \approx y ln y$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael: right, but given that $x/\log x$ isn't such a good approximation ($\text{Li}(x)$ is better), one can wonder if the extra term is helpful (or even worse).

Comment: @ClementC. Indeed, but it does work here: [it is known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) that
$n (\log n + \log \log n - 1) < p(n) < n (\log n + \log \log n)$ for $n \ge 6$.

Answer (score 2):

To be clear about what is hinted at in the comments,
$$
f^{-1}(y) = -y\,W(-\tfrac{1}{y})
$$
where $W$ is the [Lambert-$W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). (You can verify this in Mathematica.) If you wanted an asymptotic expansion check the wiki article and plug one in.